# How can I see the number of lines changed/deleted/added for unstaged/staged files with `git status`?

Tags: git

When I run `git status`, I can see that certain files have been modified, but that get no more information. Is there any way to see the total number of lines changed/deleted/added in these files, even if they are unstaged/uncommitted?

This would be helpful because I sometimes make major changes to one file, then really minor changes to other files spontaneously. I would like to commit these groups separately, and with separate commit messages, for organization. And having this capability with `git status` would help me determine at-a-glance which files have had only very minor changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there any way to see the total number of lines changed/deleted/added in these files, even if they are unstaged/uncommitted?*

Yes, `git diff --stat`. Though this won't show untracked files.

`git diff` shows the difference between the working copy and the staging area. `--stat`, and various other flags, format it.

> *This would be helpful because I sometimes make major changes to one file, then really minor changes to other files spontaneously. I would like to commit these groups separately, and with separate commit messages, for organization.*

Two additional commands are handy here.

`git commit -v` will show you the full diff in your editor while you're writing the commit message. Useful for a quick review.

`git add -p` will allow you to decide which hunks to add to the staging area.

Answer (score 2):

For staged files you can do this with `git diff --staged --stat` or `git diff --cached --numstat`.